# Laravel: reverse the result of pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am using laravel 5.6 and I want to reverse the result of the pagination query. This is what I am trying to do for now:

```
$chats = Chats::where('message_id', $message_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->latest()->paginate(5);
if(!empty($chats)) {
    $data['messages'] = $chats->reverse()->values();
    $data['status'] = 200;
    $data['create_user_id'] = Auth::id();
}else{
    $data['error'] = "No chats available";
}
```

But it removes the pagination from the result.
Lets suppose I have these 10 values in table

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Now I want `6, 7, 8, 9, 10` in first page result and `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` in second page result, specifically in that order.

Please help.

Comment: why not change ->orderBy('id', 'DESC') to ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')

Comment: it brings me the oldest data again. I have edited my question again for better understanding

Comment: @Ashish 2 years after. Did you manage to find a solution to this? Or you had to build a custom solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can reversed the pagination with latest function.


   $chats = Chats::where('message_id', $message_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->latest()->paginate(20);
if(!empty($chats)) {
    $data['messages'] = $chats->values();
    $data['status'] = 200;
    $data['create_user_id'] = Auth::id();
}else{
    $data['error'] = "No chats available";
}
```

remove reverse()  because the latest() gives reverse().

Comment: I have edited my question again for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
$chats = Chats::where(....)
    ->latest()
    ->simplePaginate();
$chats->setCollection($chats->getCollection()->reverse());
return $chats;
```

so the oldest message is the last inside the collection (as you want for most chat applications) to render it at the bottom,